# Create checkboxes programatically and the get their values with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a modified version of the answer in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27558482/sql-query-results-in-tkinter), however the main structure remains the same. I was wondering how do I add check boxes to that dictionary to then iterate through the values of the check boxes? The check boxes in tkinter require a variable for which I'll eventually check, so I'm not sure of how to create the variables using this method.

How do I create the check boxes at the end of every row in the answer of the question I mention above?

I tried the following (last 2 lines):

```
            self.widgets[rowid] = {
                "rowid": ttk.Label(table, text=rowid, width=20, anchor=CENTER, relief=SUNKEN),
                "reviewer": ttk.Label(table, text=reviewer, width=20, anchor=CENTER, relief=SUNKEN),
                "task": ttk.Label(table, text=task, width=20, anchor=CENTER, relief=SUNKEN),
                "num_seconds_correction": ttk.Entry(table),
                "num_seconds": ttk.Label(table, text=num_seconds, width=20, anchor=CENTER, relief=SUNKEN),
                "start_time": ttk.Label(table, text=start_time, width=20, anchor=CENTER, relief=SUNKEN),
                "end_time": ttk.Label(table, text=start_time, width=20, anchor=CENTER, relief=SUNKEN),
                "checkbox_var": IntVar(),
                "checkbox": ttk.Checkbutton(table)
            }
```

And in the part where the widgets are placed in the grid, I tried assigning the variable to the check box and then place it on the grid (last 2 lines):

```
#this just puts everything in the grid in the right place
self.widgets[rowid]["rowid"].grid(row=row, column=0, sticky="nsew")
self.widgets[rowid]["reviewer"].grid(row=row, column=1, sticky="nsew")
self.widgets[rowid]["task"].grid(row=row, column=2, sticky="nsew")
self.widgets[rowid]["num_seconds_correction"].grid(row=row, column=3, sticky="nsew")
self.widgets[rowid]["num_seconds"].grid(row=row, column=4, sticky="nsew")
self.widgets[rowid]["start_time"].grid(row=row, column=5, sticky="nsew")
self.widgets[rowid]["end_time"].grid(row=row, column=6, sticky="nsew")

self.widgets[rowid]["checkbox"].config(variable=(self.widgets[rowid]["checkbox_var"]))
self.widgets[rowid]["checkbox"].grid(row=row, column=7, sticky="nsew")
```

That makes the check boxes show up in the correct place. Then, when I iterate through the values to see which boxes are checked, even if some of them are checked, returns 0 for all of them:

```
for rowid in sorted(self.widgets.keys()):
    check_widget = self.widgets[rowid]["checkbox"]
    delete_value = check_widget.get()
    print(delete_value)
```

This iteration returns only 0s even if the boxes are checked. What do I seem to be doing wrong here? Is it related to assigning the variables to the check boxes?

Then I tried something a little different:

```
self.check = IntVar()
self.widgets[rowid] = {
    "rowid": ttk.Label(table, text=rowid, width=20, anchor=CENTER, relief=SUNKEN),
    "reviewer": ttk.Label(table, text=reviewer, width=20, anchor=CENTER, relief=SUNKEN),
    "task": ttk.Label(table, text=task, width=20, anchor=CENTER, relief=SUNKEN),
    "num_seconds_correction": ttk.Entry(table),
    "num_seconds": ttk.Label(table, text=num_seconds, width=20, anchor=CENTER, relief=SUNKEN),
    "start_time": ttk.Label(table, text=start_time, width=20, anchor=CENTER, relief=SUNKEN),
    "end_time": ttk.Label(table, text=start_time, width=20, anchor=CENTER, relief=SUNKEN),
    "checkbox": ttk.Checkbutton(table, variable=self.check)
}
```

And then iterate over it:

```
for rowid in sorted(self.widgets.keys()):
    print(self.check.get())
```

But it only prints 0s, any ideas?

**Edit**
Here is the entire actual state of the class:

```
class Example(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        b = ttk.Button(self, text="Done!", command=self.upload_cor) #submit button
        b.pack()
        b2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Close", command=self.destroy_cor) #close button
        b2.pack(side="right")
        table = ttk.Frame(self)
        table.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        data = results #results is the nested list with the query results of rows for one day

        self.widgets = {}
        row = 0
        total=0 #this will keep track of the total of hours for that day

        #this iteration creates all the labels and positions them
        for rowid, reviewer, task, num_seconds, start_time, end_time in (data):
            row += 1

            self.check = BooleanVar()
            #this is a dictionary, this makes it easier keep track of the values inside
            #text boxes when they're changed
            self.widgets[rowid] = {
                "rowid": ttk.Label(table, text=rowid, width=20, anchor=CENTER, relief=SUNKEN),
                "reviewer": ttk.Label(table, text=reviewer, width=20, anchor=CENTER, relief=SUNKEN),
                "task": ttk.Label(table, text=task, width=20, anchor=CENTER, relief=SUNKEN),
                "num_seconds_correction": ttk.Entry(table),
                "num_seconds": ttk.Label(table, text=num_seconds, width=20, anchor=CENTER, relief=SUNKEN),
                "start_time": ttk.Label(table, text=start_time, width=20, anchor=CENTER, relief=SUNKEN),
                "end_time": ttk.Label(table, text=start_time, width=20, anchor=CENTER, relief=SUNKEN),

                "checkbox": ttk.Checkbutton(table, variable=self.check)
            }

            total = total + int(num_seconds)

            #this just puts everything in the grid in the right place
            self.widgets[rowid]["rowid"].grid(row=row, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            self.widgets[rowid]["reviewer"].grid(row=row, column=1, sticky="nsew")
            self.widgets[rowid]["task"].grid(row=row, column=2, sticky="nsew")
            self.widgets[rowid]["num_seconds_correction"].grid(row=row, column=3, sticky="nsew")
            self.widgets[rowid]["num_seconds"].grid(row=row, column=4, sticky="nsew")
            self.widgets[rowid]["start_time"].grid(row=row, column=5, sticky="nsew")
            self.widgets[rowid]["end_time"].grid(row=row, column=6, sticky="nsew")

            #self.widgets[rowid]["checkbox"].config(variable=(self.widgets[rowid]["checkbox_var"]))
            self.widgets[rowid]["checkbox"].grid(row=row, column=7, sticky="nsew")

        ttk.Label(table, text='Total:',width=20, anchor=E, relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=row+1, column=3)    #this 2 display the total hours
        ttk.Label(table, text=total, width=20, anchor=CENTER, relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=row+1, column=4) #spent on the selected day

        table.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        table.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

        # invisible row after last row gets all extra space
        table.grid_rowconfigure(row+1, weight=1)

    globals().update(locals())

    #########################
    #uploads the new values if they
    #were changed
    def upload_cor(self):

        globals().update(locals())


        for rowid in sorted(self.widgets.keys()):

            print(self.check)

            #here is where I need something to see if the boxes are checked
```

Comment: Can you provide the full code if possible. Very difficult to see how the bits and pieces you have posted fit into the answer in the question you had linked.

Comment: I can post the entire class since it is very similar to the one in the other question i mention, just a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the code from the example adding the bits you have added. This is the full code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        b = tk.Button(self, text="Done!", command=self.upload_cor)
        b.pack()
        table = tk.Frame(self)
        table.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        data = (
            (45417, "rodringof", "CSP L2 Review", 0.000394, "2014-12-19 10:08:12", "2014-12-19 10:08:12"),
            (45418, "rodringof", "CSP L2 Review", 0.000394, "2014-12-19 10:08:12", "2014-12-19 10:08:12"),
            (45419, "rodringof", "CSP L2 Review", 0.000394, "2014-12-19 10:08:12", "2014-12-19 10:08:12"),
            (45420, "rodringof", "CSP L2 Review", 0.000394, "2014-12-19 10:08:12", "2014-12-19 10:08:12"),
            (45421, "rodringof", "CSP L2 Review", 0.000394, "2014-12-19 10:08:12", "2014-12-19 10:08:12"),
            (45422, "rodringof", "CSP L2 Review", 0.000394, "2014-12-19 10:08:12", "2014-12-19 10:08:12"),
            (45423, "rodringof", "CSP L2 Review", 0.000394, "2014-12-19 10:08:12", "2014-12-19 10:08:12"),
        )

        self.widgets = {}
        row = 0
        for rowid, reviewer, task, num_seconds, start_time, end_time in (data):
            row += 1
            self.widgets[rowid] = {
                "rowid": tk.Label(table, text=rowid),
                "reviewer": tk.Label(table, text=reviewer),
                "task": tk.Label(table, text=task),
                "num_seconds_correction": tk.Entry(table),
                "num_seconds": tk.Label(table, text=num_seconds),
                "start_time": tk.Label(table, text=start_time),
                "end_time": tk.Label(table, text=start_time),
                "checkbox_var": tk.IntVar(),
                "checkbox": tk.Checkbutton(table)
            }

            self.widgets[rowid]["rowid"].grid(row=row, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            self.widgets[rowid]["reviewer"].grid(row=row, column=1, sticky="nsew")
            self.widgets[rowid]["task"].grid(row=row, column=2, sticky="nsew")
            self.widgets[rowid]["num_seconds_correction"].grid(row=row, column=3, sticky="nsew")
            self.widgets[rowid]["num_seconds"].grid(row=row, column=4, sticky="nsew")
            self.widgets[rowid]["start_time"].grid(row=row, column=5, sticky="nsew")
            self.widgets[rowid]["end_time"].grid(row=row, column=6, sticky="nsew")

            self.widgets[rowid]["checkbox"].config(variable=(self.widgets[rowid]["checkbox_var"]))
            self.widgets[rowid]["checkbox"].grid(row=row, column=7, sticky="nsew")

        table.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        table.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        # invisible row after last row gets all extra space
        table.grid_rowconfigure(row+1, weight=1)

    def upload_cor(self):
        for rowid in sorted(self.widgets.keys()):
            entry_widget = self.widgets[rowid]["num_seconds_correction"]
            new_value = entry_widget.get()
            print("%s: %s" % (rowid, new_value))

        for rowid in sorted(self.widgets.keys()):
            check_var = self.widgets[rowid]["checkbox_var"]
            print(check_var.get())
            if check_var.get():
                print('Check button checked')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Specificlly have a look at `upload_cor`. As you can see, instead of `check_widget = self.widgets[rowid]["checkbox"]` I want to get the checkbox variable. I think this is the problem with your code. You get the widget, rather than a variable associated with the widget. Hope it helps.